# Открытие диалогового окна в windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

открытие диалогового окна замораживает программу (программа при нажатии кнопки зависает)
вот функционал данной кнопки

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string t = "";
            FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                t = dialog.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
```

не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Может на другом экране открывается окно? Попробуйте обычный OpenFileDialog проверить

Comment: Открытие диалогового окна и должно замораживать приложение, а закрытие - размораживать. С этим всё в порядке.